# RxJava concatMap with BiFunction

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

Is there a way to create functionality of **concatMap** with **BiFunction**, like **flatMap** has? Now I use **flatMap** but I need to keep the order.

The code populates every object in the list with additional data that based on the object data.

```
private Single<List<CategoryModel>> getCategories() {
    return mService.getCategories()
                .concatMapIterable(categories -> categories)
                .flatMap(category -> mService.getItems(category.getId()), (category, items) -> {
                    category.setItems(items);
                    return category;
                })
                .toList();
}
```

Comment: You can use the [overload](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-int-) with `maxConcurrency` set to 1.

Comment: What the difference between concatMap and flatMap with maxConcurrency 1 then?

Comment: There work with different internal tradeoffs which doesn't effect the user in general.